# toolbar center textview when there is menu item

Tags: android, toolbar, centering

After reading multiple Question/Answer in SO, I'm still searching for an answer.
My problem: in my application I use a Toolbar, but depending on the Fragment/Activity you're in the Toolbar menu item could change, for exemple on the first screen you will see only a Textview, in an other Fragment there will be the home arrow and an overflow menu sometimes there is two menu icons. The problem is that the title is centered with the space avaible wich is (toolbar space - menuitem space)

Here is my Toolbar xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/ciwy"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I tried contentInserStart but it doesn't change anything. I also used a relativelayout to center the textview. I need it to work atleast on API 19 (to try it on my phone).

Is there a solution to center the Textview in the middle of the bar even if I have menu items?

**EDIT**
Not finding any solution I just added an Image view in the RelativeLayout to act like the home button.

Comment: I don't think there will be a simple solution. The `Toolbar` allots space for the remaining views based on the number of menu items there are. Therefore, when you add a `TextView` to the `Toolbar` and center it, you are centering it in the remaining space available. The reason the `Toolbar` takes the menu items into account is to prevent overlap; so if you want to have a view perfectly centered and avoid overlap, you will most likely have to sub-class `Toolbar`.

Comment: Try also adding `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` to your `Toolbar`

Comment: app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation doesn't work.

Comment: What about: `android:gravity=center' in `<TextView>` widget.

Comment: @SatanPandeya Doesn't work, still center depending on the space left